# Facebook pixel does not send data on PageView

Tags: facebook-pixel

Facebook Pixel Helper plugin says that the code is in the page, but it isn't able to track.

These are the errors

[image: Text]

Pixel code seems to be well inserted in the page, before 
Also the event, just after

[Facebook guide](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/153210695223635?id=1205376682832142) seems to say to do anything else that put the code in the page for events.